# How to implement proper navigation similar to YouTube's and Instagram's using Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, fragment-backstack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am having difficulty with implementing a proper navigation structure in my app. I want it to behave similarly to the navigation in YouTube and Instagram. The biggest problem I am having is with the backstack and fragment recreation.

I'm currently using the single activity with multiple fragments approach. I have an app bar and bottom navigation view with 3 menu items setup in the main activity. The app bar has one menu item that navigates to the user profile fragment when selected, and each of the bottom nav's menu items navigates to different root fragments(home, search, and profile) when selected. I'm also using google's firebase database and firestore to store user data(email, uid, password, etc...) and photos.

I've tried using the supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace way, and android jetpack's navigation architecture, but haven't been able to produce the results I need with either.

I'm able to navigate to the proper destinations using the supportFragmentManager way, but can't seem to implement a proper backwards navigation structure. I've tried to find other code samples of implementing this, but was unable to find anything that works, and a lot of these samples are older versions in java code with deprecated methods, which makes it difficult when trying to convert to kotlin code.

The jetpack navigation component is a bit easier to use, but I cannot get it to behave properly either. To my knowledge, the current navigation does not support multiple backstacks and does not have a proper backwards navigation structure unless you add the NavigationExtensions file provided here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample. Using this sample, I am having problems with:

1.Navigating backwards does not return to the originally saved fragment state, it instead recreates a brand new fragment.

2.Navigating to the profile fragment from the app bar works, but crashes when the user is inside the fragment and presses it again.

3.Passing a default set of arguments to the user fragment item menu in the bottom navigation view. I originally had the account profile fragment tied to a bottom nav menu item (still do for testing purposes) with the logged in user's uid set as the default arguments. The fragment(UserFragment) used takes the uid argument and uses it to fetch the proper information from google's firebase. I was previously able to achieve this by using the regular jetpack navigation component(without the advanced sample) and adding the following code in the MainActivity:

```
val navArgument1 = NavArgument.Builder().setDefaultValue(uid).build()
val orderDestination = navController.graph.findNode(R.id.user_Fragment)
orderDestination?.addArgument("destinationUid",navArgument1)
```

Then within the user fragment, I use this code to get the proper uid:

```
uid = arguments?.getString("destinationUid")
```

With the advanced sample navigation component, I'm not able to pass this default argument into the user fragment. I keep getting an error that says something like "There is no navigation controller associated with this fragment," and the app crashes.

## The Main Activity

```
class ExploreActivity : AppCompatActivity(),BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(p0:MenuItem):Boolean{

        when(p0.itemId){
            R.id.home->{
                val homeViewFragment = HomeViewFragment()
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,homeViewFragment).commit()
                return true
            }
            R.id.world->{
                val publicViewFragment = PublicViewFragment()
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,publicViewFragment).commit()
                return true
            }
            R.id.account->{
                val userFragment = UserFragment()
                val bundle = Bundle()
                val uid=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid

                bundle.putString("destinationUid",uid)
                userFragment.arguments=bundle

                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,userFragment).commit()
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_explore)

        bottom_navigation_explore.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
        bottom_navigation_explore.selectedItemId=R.id.home

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode:Int,resultCode:Int,data:Intent?){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data)

        if(requestCode==UserFragment.PICK__PROFILE_FROM_ALBUM&&resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){
            val imageUri=data?.data
            val uid=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
            val storageRef=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("userProfileImages")
                .child(uid!!)

            storageRef.putFile(imageUri!!).continueWithTask{task:Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>->
                return@continueWithTask storageRef.downloadUrl
            }.addOnSuccessListener{uri->
                val map=HashMap<String,Any>()
                map["image"]=uri.toString()
                FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("profileImages").document(uid).set(map)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## User Fragment

```
class UserFragment : Fragment(){

    var fragmentView : View? = null
    var firestore : FirebaseFirestore? = null
    var uid : String? = null
    var auth : FirebaseAuth? = null
    var currentUserUid : String? = null

    companion object{
        var PICK__PROFILE_FROM_ALBUM = 10
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        fragmentView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container,false)

        uid = arguments?.getString("destinationUid")
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        currentUserUid = auth?.currentUser?.uid

        return fragmentView
        }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        if(uid == currentUserUid) {

            fragmentView?.btn_follow_signout_main?.text = "Signout"
            fragmentView?.btn_follow_signout_main?.setOnClickListener {
                activity?.finish()
                startActivity(Intent(activity, LoginActivity::class.java))
                auth?.signOut()
            }
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),1)

            iv_createpost_main.setOnClickListener {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context!!, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                  
                    startActivity(Intent(activity,CreatePost::class.java))
                }
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

            //add explanation of why permission is needed
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context!!, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                iv_profilepicture_main.setOnClickListener {

                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
                    intent.type = "image/*"
                    activity?.startActivityForResult(intent, PICK__PROFILE_FROM_ALBUM)
                }
            }
        }
                    else{
            fragmentView?.btn_follow_signout_main?.text = "Follow +"
            fragmentView?.btn_follow_signout_main?.setOnClickListener {
                requestFollow()
            }
        }


        getProfileImage()
        getUserName()
    }

    private fun getProfileImage() {

        firestore?.collection("profileImages")!!.document(uid!!).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if(task.isSuccessful){
                val url = task.result!!["image"]
                if(url != null){
                    Glide.with(activity!!).load(url).into(iv_profilepicture_main)
                }
                else{
                    iv_profilepicture_main.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_account)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getUserName(){
        firestore?.collection("users")!!.document(uid!!).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if(task.isSuccessful){
                val username = task.result!!["username"]
                if(username != null){
                    activity?.setTitle("" + username)
                }
            }
        }
    }

        }
```

My project is currently setup using the support fragment manager, but I've been going back and forth between using it and the navigation component to try and make things work.

I have two other fragments tied to the bottom nav, but I've only included the relevant code where I believe my problem lies. The other two fragments have a user profile picture that navigates the user to the selected profile when it is clicked. I do not have any problems with those transactions, because I can easily apply the bundle and arguments with the setOnClickListener method.

## TL;DR

To summarize everything: I am looking for a way to implement a proper navigation flow throughout my app. I'm having problems with backwards navigation and fragments being recreated when they shouldn't. I've tried using the fragment manager and the android jetpack navigation component, but haven't had luck with either. If anyone has any information on how to achieve this using android kotlin and the latest methods, and would like to share, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Not your question, but you should not store plaintext passwords (anywhere). You should salt & hash them (using a "slow" hash algorithm), but since you're using Firebase already I encourage you to migrate to Firebase Auth.

Comment: @AjahnCharles 
Thanks for the advice, but I'm not familiar with "salt & hash." I'll have to research it some more, but I believe I am using Firebase Auth. That is how I am able to retrieve and check the user's uid.

Comment: Did you find a solution to prevent fragments being recreated?